# Use libpcap and sockets to transmit a packet whenever you receive

Tags: c, sockets, libpcap, libnet

I am trying to make a program, so that whenever I receive a packet in an interface from a specific MAC address I want to transmit another packet (the reply packets contained in a pcap file). The program below partially works.It has two problems.

There is no way to achieve synchronization, i.e. transmit whenever I receive.

Additionally, for some unknown reason,despite the replay pcap file that I want to use as a response to every packet that I receive,contains 65000 packets, only 800 are transmitted (unsynchronized again) and the program terminates with no errors...

Any thoughts? Thank you!

```
#include <time.h>
#include <pcap.h>
#include <libnet.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <netpacket/packet.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>


int make_raw_sock(const char *interface, struct sockaddr_ll *sa);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   const char *srcmac;
   char mac[]={0x28,0x63,0x36,0x91,0x3c,0x0e};

   //SET UP FOR INJECTING SOCKET
   //Buffer to send data.
   char buf[1514];
   struct sockaddr_ll sa;
   const u_char *packetstored;
   const u_char *packetrx;
   struct pcap_pkthdr headerst;
   struct pcap_pkthdr headerrx;
   pcap_t *mypcapfile;
   pcap_t *p;


   //Create the socket for injection.
   int ps = 0;  
   ps = make_raw_sock("lo", &sa);
   if (ps<0) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"Failure in socket creation\n");
      exit(-1);
   }
   //PARAMETERS FOR LIBPCAP
   //The maximum number of packets to be captured.
   //uint32_t count = 250000;
   //The snapshot lenght.
   uint32_t snaplen = 1514;     
   //Buffer for errors.
   char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];  
   //Set interface in promiscuous mode.
   int promisc = 1;                
   //timeout, in milliseconds.
   int to_ms = 1000;                              

   fprintf(stdout,"Parent process id = %d\n",getpid());

   if (!(p = pcap_open_live("lo", snaplen, promisc, to_ms, errbuf)))
   {
       fprintf(stderr, "Error opening interface %s: %s\n","lo", errbuf);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   mypcapfile = pcap_open_offline("replay3.pcap", errbuf);
   if (mypcapfile == NULL) 
   {
       printf("Error pcap_open_offline(): %s\n", errbuf);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }


   int counter;
   while (1)
   {
        packetrx = pcap_next(p, &headerrx);
        srcmac =  packetrx;
        if (packetrx == NULL)
        {
           break;
        }
        else
        {
           if (!strncmp(srcmac,mac,6))
           { 
              packetstored = pcap_next(mypcapfile, &headerst);
              memcpy(buf,packetstored,headerst.caplen);
              sendto(ps, buf, headerst.caplen, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa));
              counter = counter + 1;
           }
        }

   }
   fprintf(stdout,"Packets sent:%d\n",counter);
   return (0);
}

 int make_raw_sock(const char *interface, struct sockaddr_ll *sa) 
{
int ps;
struct ifreq ifr;

ps = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
if (ps < 0) 
{
  return ps;
}

strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, interface);
if (ioctl(ps, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) != 0) 
{
  close(ps);
  return -1;
}

memset(sa, 0, sizeof(*sa));
sa->sll_family = AF_PACKET;
sa->sll_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
sa->sll_halen = sizeof(struct ether_addr);
return ps;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `strncmp` on something that isn't a C string (NUL-terminated character array)? It is perfectly acceptable for a MAC address to have a byte that is zero in it.

Comment: Also, add debug prints, and stop ignoring the result of `sendto`. We can't debug this program for you. If you want to work with a thing as complex as a raw socket, you need at least debugging skills.

Comment: 1. That's why I am using str_n_cmp (There is no null byte)     2. I did strace -p procid. It does not fail, and exits normally. 3. I don't want you to debug, just check the flow of the program.

Comment: `str*` is wrong to use here. Use `memcmp`. There are two ways I can see that packets aren't sent: the MAC comparison fails, or sendto returns error. Simply adding a printf in each case will make this obvious.